# How to change the imageview resource in gridview?

Tags: java, android, gridview, layout

I have two GridView

```
     <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:background="#59A9D2" >
    </GridView>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridViewMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gridView"
        android:background="#1E98D5" >
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

First grid view holds 25 imageView elements.

Second grid view holds 5 images (these 5 images are from the 25 images from the first grid view images)

User can able to click only on the images of first grid view. user need to find out the second grid view images in first grid view.

when the user successfully make a correct click. i want the that image to turn into a "right green tick" image in the second grid how to do this onitemclicklistener of first grid view.

mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // ToastMessage(position);

            if ((mRandomIDList.toArray()[position] == mSolutionList
                    .toArray()[tempposition])) {

                Score = Score + (TimeLeft * (tempposition + 1));
                mScoreTextView.setText("Score: " + Score);
                //mGridViewMain.getAdapter().getView(tempposition, checkImageView, null);
                //mGridViewMain.notifyAll();
                if(mMediaPlayer2.isPlaying()){
                mMediaPlayer2.stop();
                }
                mMediaPlayer2.start();
                tempposition++;
                //Marking the try one image in solution grid view
                if (tempposition == 5) {
                    mCountDownTimer.cancel();
                    Intent successIntent = new Intent(mContext,
                            SuccesActivity.class);
                    successIntent.putExtra("last-score", Score);
                    successIntent.putExtra("Game Level", PLAY_LEVEL);
                    startActivity(successIntent);
                    mMediaPlayer.stop();
                    mMediaPlayer.reset();
                    mMediaPlayer.release();
                    finish();
                }
            } else {
                mCountDownTimer.cancel();
                GameOver(mContext, Score);
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                mMediaPlayer.reset();
                mMediaPlayer.release();
                finish();
            }
```

Comment: does the two Gridview in same activity?

Comment: yes it is in same activity.

Comment: can anybody help me to fix this issue pls.

Comment: The fix has been made.